# Permission set error while installing unlocked package

Tags: salesforcedx, permission-sets, unlocked-package

I have created an unlocked package version and while trying to install it in production, I am getting an error:

> Permission Create Invoice_Approver__c depends on permission(s): Read Order__c  InvoiceBook_Permission_Set: Permission Create Invoice_Approver__c depends on permission(s): Read Order__c

But what confusing me is there is no relationship created between `Invoice_Approver__c` and `Order__c` object. `Order__c` is a custom object created directly in production.

So not sure why the unlocked package object is getting referenced to `Order__c` which is not even part of the package.

Looking forward to having inputs from everyone to fix this issue.